# Calling a Method using the Input of the User (using their String)

Tags: ruby

I am attempting to use the String from a variable to call a Method within the program.

How can one use the String from the Variable to call said Method without having to nest or make multiple checks?

```
module Player
  @@location = "location"

  def Player.input(input)
    if input == "look"
      "Call Method from @@location"
    end
  end

  def Player.set_location(input)
    @@location = input
  end
end

def input
  print "> "
  Player.input(@stdin.gets.chomp)
end

def "name of Method can be same as @@location"
  ...
end

def "another name of Method can be same as @@location"
  ...
end

def "another name, etc"
  ...
end
```

Comment: Are you looking for [Object#send](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Object.html#method-i-send)?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. In your question title, in your first paragraph, and in your second paragraph you ask about *calling* a method, but then in your code you show examples of *defining* methods. Also, "name of method is same as `@@location`" and "another name of method is same as `@@location`" doesn't make sense. If both names are the as `@@location`, then both names are the same, or in other words: there is *only one name*, and not "another name".

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases?

Comment: @JörgWMittag I understand your confusion, and I apologize. @@location can be changed by a setter within the Player module, but that setter is not shown.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Your other answer, about the "defining methods": The method being called is found within Player.input.

module Player
  @@location = "location"

  def Player.input(input)
    if input == "look"
      "Call Method from @@location"
    end
  end
end

Comment: @itdoesntwork Looking over Object#send, it appears to be what I am looking for, but in practice, I can't get it to convert a string into a means to call a Method.

Comment: @itdoesntwork Object#send was it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by *without having to nest* ? I wonder if your code is a contrived example. Defining methods in the special object `main` is OK for a quick test, if they are also called from `main`, otherwise they must be put in a class.

So the answer could be as simple as that :

```
module Player
  @location = 'location'

  def Player.input(input)
    puts "in Player.input(#{input})"
    if input == 'look'
      puts "Calling method <#{@location}>"
      Switch.send(@location)
    else
      puts 'wrong input, must be "look"'
    end
  end

  def Player.set_location(input)
    @location = input
  end
end

def input
  print "> "
  Player.input(gets.chomp)
end

class Switch
    def self.abc
      puts 'in abc'
    end

    def self.def
      puts 'in def'
    end

    def self.location
      puts 'in location'
    end

    def self.method_missing(name, *args, &block)
      puts "There is no method #{name} in #{self.name}" 
    end
end

input
input
Player.set_location('abc')
input
Player.set_location('xyz')
input
```

Execution :

```
$ ruby -w t.rb 
> looc
in Player.input(looc)
wrong input, must be "look"
> look
in Player.input(look)
Calling method <location>
in location
> look
in Player.input(look)
Calling method <abc>
in abc
> look
in Player.input(look)
Calling method <xyz>
There is no method xyz in Switch
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!